# angular application stopped loading at the auth action

Tags: angular-routing, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, angular15, msal-angular

the MSAL for Angular library is in use with the Azure AD B2C custom policy. In some specific cases, for example when opening browser with restored session and logging in, the application stops loading at the `auth` controller action.
The exact steps to reproduce the issue are:

- Login to the application,
- Logout,
- Close the browser,
- Open the browser with the previous session restored,
- Login with a different user credentials.

The application stops loading with a blank screen at the `auth` action. It doesn't proceed to the default page.

The routing is configured correctly:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    // Needed for handling redirect after login
    path: 'auth',
    component: MsalRedirectComponent
  },
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
     .....
    })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
```

The `MsalRedirectComponent` is correctly bootstrapped and configured [according to the documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/redirects.md#1-msalredirectcomponent-a-dedicated-handleredirectobservable-component)

There is no error in the logs. I have set the logging level `verbose`, but there is no information about what went wrong.

`app.module.ts` has the `MsalRedirectComponent` bootstrapped:

```
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
    MsalRedirectComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

the `index.html` also has the needed directive:

```
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-redirect></app-redirect>
</body>
```

Versions:

- Angular 15.1.3
- @azure/msal-angular 2.5.3
- azure/msal-browser 2.33.0
- msal 1.4.17